# SQL- Insert Into PHP-prepare Statement False Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am new to Databases and the mysqli-workflow. I don't understand what is wrong with this statement and its Syntax. I already checked other codes and the way it was in their description was not the problem that I have.
My code:

```
$absenden = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO Anmeldung(Bestaetigt, Schluessel, Vorname, Nachname, Einschulungsjahr, Grundschule, GeschwisterAufStein, KlasseGeschwister, Geschlecht, KlassenlehrerGrundschule, Geburtsdatum, Geburtsort, AufnahmeDatum, StraßeHausnummerKind, PLZKind, OrtKind, Staatsangehoerigkeit, Fremdsprache, Schuelerjahreskarte, Konfession, MigrationJahr, MigrationSprache, MigrationLand, VornameVater, NachnameVater, GeburtslandVater, StraßeHausnummerVater, PLZVater, OrtVater, VornameMutter, NachnameMutter, GeburtslandMutter, StraßeHausnummerMutter, PLZMutter, OrtMutter, HandyVater, HandyMutter, TelefonPrivat, DienstVater, DienstMutter, TelefonNotfall, E-Mail, Nutzermail, Zweitwunsch, Bemerkungen) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

It says there is a problem near the VALUES in the error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-Mail, Nutzermail, Zweitwunsch, Bemerkungen) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ' at line 1 in /users/schulanmeldung/www/Leonard/index.php:265 Stack trace: #0 /users/schulanmeldung/www/Leonard/index.php(265): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO Anm...') #1 {main} thrown in /users/schulanmeldung/www/Leonard/index.php on line 265
```

Comment: `E-Mail` is not a valid column name. It's subtracting one column name from the other, which semantically doesn't make sense there. Also, MySQL isn't forcing anyone to write unreadable oneliners.

Comment: Oh thank you, you helped me a lot, in my editor it automatically splits the line.

Comment: I know this is an old post that has received no answers but this tidbit: All the column names should be surrounded by back-ticks which tells MySQL what it is. Same with the table names.